# RemoteServiceException on all OnePlus One devies running Android 8.0

Tags: android, runtimeexception, android-8.0-oreo, oneplusone

Have the following app crash in android vitals with some specific information as under, I have no clue what is the root cause, looked around for some similar cases but no luck. If anyone faced the same thing or have any pointers they would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Android version: only on Android 8.0 devices.

> All OnePlus One devices in the list of devices this is failing.

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1870)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6809)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Issue occurred only for OnePlus devices with android version 8.0 and greater.

Comment: Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: can't deliver broadcast
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1867)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: @bluemoonstudios I am also facing this issue.if there is any solution please let me know.

Comment: did you find any solution?